# Append a string to the beginning of second line using unix

Tags: text-processing

I want to append a string to the beginning of second line of my text file, for example:

```
1
2
3
```

should become:

```
1
42
3
```

Any idea about how to go about with this thing?

Answer (score 9):

You could do this with sed, if you have GNU sed you can use `-i` to modify it in place as follows

```
sed -i -e '2s/^/4/' source
```

This will tell `sed` to modify in place (`-i`) and to execute the regular expression substitution (`s/^/4/`) to match the start of the line (`^`) with a `4`, and to only do that on line number `2`. All of this is done on the file named `source`

Comment: It's not really "in place", though. `sed` writes to a temporary file and then renames that to the original filename.

Comment: @roaima that's true about how it does the modification, but the name of the long option is actually "--in-place" and the end result is that the original filename now has the updated contents (provided you had enough free disk space to make the temporary copy).  So it does modify the file with the given name such that at the end of the operation it will have the updated contents in place, but it uses an intermediary along the way, a subtle but occasionally crucial distinction

Comment: With a small file the difference is mostly irrelevant, agreed. But for (very) large files one might need a true "in place" operation. Or hard-linked files, of course.

Answer (score 7):

POSIX one:

```
printf '\n4' | paste -d'\0' - file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc '2s/^/4/|x' file
```

1. `2` select second line
2. `s` substitute
3. `x` save and close

Answer (score 0):

Obligatory `awk` solution:

```
awk -v prepend="<your-text-here>" 'NR==2{print prepend $0;next};1' file
```

Or the environment-variable solution proposed by [@cuonglm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224262/append-a-string-to-the-beginning-of-second-line-using-unix#comment381362_224366)'s comment:

```
prepend="<your-text-here>" awk 'NR==2{print ENVIRON["prepend"] $0;next};1' file
```

- `-v prepend=...` assigns a variable in `awk` called `prepend` with the specified value.
- `NR==2` applies the following command for the 2nd line.
- `print prepend $0` prepends to the line, remember to `next` to skip to the next line.
- The final `1` is a shortcut for `{print $0}`, which is to print the whole line.

Comment: It's better to pass `prepend` from environment then get it in `awk` by `ENVIRON["prepend"]`. Escape sequence inside variable assign by `-v` will be expanded by `awk`.

Comment: @cuonglm thanks for the advice, have added to my answer.