# How to add text to the start of a line?

Tags: text-processing

I have a text file and I want to prepend some text to the first line.
I tried something like this:

```
sed -i '1i\'"string" file
```

However this inserts a new line to the text file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work with GNU sed:

```
sed -i '1s/^/string/' file
```

it's different from your solution in not adding the new line.

#### test

Before running command, the content of file is this:

```
some
text
here
already
```

After running the command:

```
stringsome
text
here
already
```

Comment: @lese if you remove the `\n` from your command I think it answers the question, OP is looking for text in front of their first line rather than a new first line.

Answer (score 1):

Another way (similar to [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/224268/38906) in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/224262/38906)):

```
printf 'string' | paste -d'\0' - infile > outfile
```

or:

```
printf string | cat - infile > outfile
```

or:

```
{ printf string; cat infile; } > outfile
```

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Yep, or without subshell `{ printf string; cat infile; } > outfile`